# scatter plot logarithmic scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

In my code, I take the logarithm of two data series and plot them. I would like to change each tick value of the x-axis by raising it to the power of e (anti-log of natural logarithm).

In other words. I want to graph the logarithms of both series but have x-axis in levels.

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
from pylab import scatter
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy as np

file_name = '/Users/joedanger/Desktop/Python/scatter_python.csv'

data = DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file_name))

y = np.log(data['o_value'], dtype='float64')
x = np.log(data['time_diff_day'], dtype='float64')

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, c='blue', alpha=0.05, edgecolors='none')
fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('time_diff_day', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('o_value', fontsize=16)
plt.xticks([-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4])

plt.grid(True)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

let `matplotlib` take the log for you:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.scatter(data['o_value'] ,data['time_diff_day'] , c='blue', alpha=0.05, edgecolors='none')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

If you are using all the same size and color markers, it is faster to use `plot`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(data['o_value'] ,data['time_diff_day'], 'o', c='blue', alpha=0.05, markeredgecolor='none')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

Comment: @tcaswell I'm having trouble using `plt.yscale('log')` after a `plt.scatter()` and have described the problem [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38800189/3904031).

Comment: does `ax.set_yscale('log')` use np.log or np.log1p for the conversion?

Answer (score 44):

The accepted answer is a bit out of date. At least pandas 0.25 natively supports log axes:

```
# logarithmic X
df.plot.scatter(..., logx=True)
# logarithmic Y
df.plot.scatter(..., logy=True)
# both
df.plot.scatter(..., loglog=True)
```