# Why does matplotlib require setting log scale before plt.scatter() but not plt.plot()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I found out in this [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800032/3904031) that `plt.scatter()` and  `plt.plot()` behave differently when a logrithmic scale is used on the y axis.

With `plot`, I can change to log any time before I use `plt.show()`, but log has to be set up-front, *before* the scatter method is used.

Is this just a historical and irreversible artifact in matplotlib, or is this in the 'unexpected behavior' category?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [0.997, 2.643, 0.354, 0.075, 1.0, 0.03, 2.39, 0.364, 0.221, 0.437]
Y = [15.487507, 2.320735, 0.085742, 0.303032, 1.0, 0.025435, 4.436435,
     0.025435, 0.000503, 2.320735]

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('scatter - scale last')   

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('plot - scale last')   

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.title('scatter - scale first')   


plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.title('plot - scale first')   


plt.show()
```

Comment: We might need to trudge through `matplotlib`'s source code to answer this, unless someone familiar with it stumbles here.

Comment: @Kartik trudging through source code might pinpoint a proximal cause - I'm sure this behavior is exactly what the source code calls for. But from the point of view of using the plot and scatter methods - is there some benefit from or intent for this different behavior, or is it something that falls into the category of things that could be improved?

Comment: @Kartik there are people very familiar with matplotlib that do a lot more than stumbling here. I'm asking this here because I have a hunch someone well versed in matplotlib will help me understand if it's possible to pursue a change in the scatter method, or if it's one of those things that's just not going to happen. Maybe there is actually a benefit to this difference I haven't noticed too!

Comment: To differentiate between the "irreversible artifact"  and "unexpected behaviour" source code is the only way I can see of doing it. I know that it behaves exactly as in the source code, but maybe it is caused by an omitted line that recalculates axes.

Comment: @Kartik it's possible someone simply knows the answer already. Matplotlib has been with us quite a while now.

Comment: I suggest you also open an issue on matplotlib git hub about this. Perhaps it will be shot down as an intended feature, or perhaps it will result in an update.

Comment: @uhoh It's just a y limit scale issue. Look at the y limits of your left two plots.

Comment: @Suever That's sort-of an `None` type comment. "It's a scale issue, look at the axis" I took some time to write the question in only three sentences, then added a plot and script to demonstrate the differences. if you have a chance, take another look?

Comment: @uhoh I'm not sure why you think it's a crap comment. I'm simply pointing out that the difference seems to be due to how the ylimits are selected. If you call `plt.gca().relim()` you still get the incorrect range of the y axes. Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18774741/670206) by one of the developers calling `xscale` and `yscale` after creation shouldn't be a problem so I'm guessing this is a bug of sorts.

Comment: @Suever well I think that is an extremely helpful comment this time. Since I'm not really a *Matplotlib Black Belt*, I thought you were telling me to actually visually look at the axis in the plot on my screen. Now I understand that you meant *look at the axis object in python*!  Actually (at)tcaswell is exactly who I was hoping would see this and comment with the best way to view the situation here - is this a bug, a 'feature' or just simply cast in concrete. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @Kartik I've taken the plunge - matplotlib issue #6915 in Github.

Comment: I have subscribed to the issue. Let's see where it leads.

Comment: Please keep these comments thread a bit less heated.

Comment: Matplotlib [issue #6915](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6915) has now been superseded by [issue #7413](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413) in Github

Comment: Perhaps its because plot is connected and scatter is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This somehow has to do with the the display area (axes limits) calculated by `matplotlib`.

This behaviour is fixed by manually editing the axes range by using `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` methods.

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([min(X),max(X)])
axes.set_ylim([min(Y),max(Y)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The exact reason of this behavior is however not yet figured out by me. Suggestions are welcomed.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments section, apparently Matplotlib has identified [Autoscaling has fundamental problems](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413) as a *Release Critical Issue* on their official Github repo, which would be fixed in upcoming versions. Thanks.

Comment: If you check the comments under the question, you'll see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800189/why-does-matplotlib-require-setting-log-scale-before-plt-scatter-but-not-plt-p/56129835#comment78167310_38800189) which links to more information. If you add a link to the second one [Autoscaling has fundamental problems #7413](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413) I will accept your answer and this question can be closed!

Comment: @uhoh Done. Thanks.

Comment: one more SO question answered, only [5,189,568 to go](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)! ;-)