# python matplotlib.pyplot log-log plot points not showing because the y range is poorly chosen by python

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code that generates a log-log plot, python picks an x range that does not show the points on the scatter plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter([.005,.005],[1,2])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Additionally, if you instead use the following code, it works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([.005,.005],[1,2])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Usually python picks a good range for both the x and y values. Why does it not in this case?

Please note that I am aware it is possible to change the x and y ranges so that the default is not used. My question is specifically asking why python does not choose a good range in this case.

Thanks

I appears this is a duplicate of [Why does matplotlib require setting log scale before plt.scatter() but not plt.plot()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800189/why-does-matplotlib-require-setting-log-scale-before-plt-scatter-but-not-plt-p)

To anyone reading this, please let me know if I should remove this question or if you'd recommend something else. Thanks

Comment: What's strange is that `plt.plot([.005,.005],[1,2], 'o')` works fine

Comment: you have a good point, that is very strange, I'll add that to the question, thanks

Comment: A similar issue had been raised [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6915). If you look at the end of the discussion, you will find the same alternate as I suggested: use `plt.plot` with `o` as markers

Comment: your link provides a link back to a SO question that is unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800189/why-does-matplotlib-require-setting-log-scale-before-plt-scatter-but-not-plt-p

Comment: I didn't go through the complete thread of discussion but I thought of just sharing it with you. @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest might be aware of updates. Wait for his response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from various threads ([this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6915), [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413), [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11198),   [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800189/why-does-matplotlib-require-setting-log-scale-before-plt-scatter-but-not-plt-p)) we can conclude that this is a probematic issue to solve. ...but only if you require to set the scale *after* the plotting.

If you set the scale **before** plotting, it's not a problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter([.005,.005],[1,2])

plt.show()
```